# How to use a single QPainter in python?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

I have read that [using a single QPainter is not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45732234/6285023), but I'm struggling to understand what the effect of doing so is.

Take this first example:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Canvas(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        self.__painter.eraseRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height())
        self.__painter.drawRect(20, 20, self.width() - 40, self.height() - 40)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
win = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
canvas = Canvas(win)
win.setCentralWidget(canvas)
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Nothing gets drawn, the output is as follows, with the *`Painter not active`* message printed on each `paintEvent` call:

```
QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
QPainter::drawRects: Painter not active
```

For the initial `paintEvent`, how does this differ from creating the `QPainter` inside the event handler ?

If then, guided by the error messages I add some manual `begin()` and `end()` calls, I'm able to get rid of the *`Painter not active`* messages, but:

- the first two ones remain
- how is this that the `QPainter` apparently gets `end()`'ed, possibly even before being used ?

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Canvas(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        self.__painter.begin(self)
        self.__painter.eraseRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height())
        self.__painter.drawRect(20, 20, self.width() - 40, self.height() - 40)
        self.__painter.end()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
win = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
canvas = Canvas(win)
win.setCentralWidget(canvas)
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: [The documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtGui/QPainter.html#detailed-description) says quite straightforwardly that you cannot do this. it's also not clear what problem you hope to solve: *why is it a problem* to create a temporary, local `QPainter` in the `paintEvent`?

Comment: Also, the same documentation says: "When the paintdevice is a widget, QPainter can only be used inside a paintEvent() function or in a function called by paintEvent()." This is valid also for calling `begin()` on QPainter (which is implicit when the paint device is given as argument in the constructor). The first warning is probably a result of the attempt to `begin()` and a generic warning for which it is *assumed* what the docs warn you about: you cannot call it outside of a paint event. I agree with Karl, the construction of a new, temporary painter is quite fast, the call to `begin()` is->

Comment: ->anyway required (which is fundamentally the most "heavy" part of the painter initialization), so there is really no benefit in trying to reuse the same QPainter object since both `begin()` and `end()` become mandatory. If you believe that this would improve performance, that's not the case: it would only make things more complex and prone to problems. If you really want to improve performance, consider caching possibly by using QPicture to avoid python bottlenecks for drawing computation, pen/brush/brush/color/gradient creation, etc.

Comment: Ah, @karl-knechtel you mean the _When the paintdevice is a widget, QPainter can only be used inside a paintEvent() function or in a function called by paintEvent()._ part, I guess.  I can in fact change the code, so the painter gets initialized to None, and a getter constructs the `QPainter`.  Together with a handful of begin/end calls it allows to circumvent that limitation.
Now why I'm trying to do this is likely a design issue in my app, I'll try to improve that design.

Comment: @YannDirson yes, but, as said, there's little to ***no*** benefit in reusing it. Can you explain why are you trying to do so?

Comment: @musicamante design issue, likely.  I'll update if I find out I really need it.

Comment: @YannDirson I strongly believe that you won't. The *extremely little* benefit you'd have by using a "shared" QPainter would most certainly create more issues in a way or the other, at least from the code perspective. Yes, it is *possible* that you might gain some slightly performance increase, but the amount of code fail-safes you'd need to implement will probably not be worth it. OOP is known to have some performance issues caused by its structure and object hierarchy, but, luckily, we're not in the '90s anymore. Most of the times, it's just a problem with the implementation.

Comment: @YannDirson If you get to the point where you have *thousands* of widgets and your issue is about drawing performance, maybe your problem is not about creating new QPainter instances, but the whole structure. Maybe you should consider using the [graphics view framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html), some level of caching, or a completely different way of creating the whole UI. Otherwise, if performance is paramount and there are hundreds (or thousands) of widgets that need continuous painting, maybe you should move away from Python at all.

Comment: @musicamante no the reason was a bad design idea, and I had no problem to put it straight. Constraints sometime help ;)

How do we close this question, do you wish to submit an answer so I can accept it ?